# ng-options is not working with select dropdown of bootstrap via angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

as ng-options is not working in my select button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
..
...
<label class="input-label">Select among this :</label> <select
                    class="selectpicker" multiple
                    data-selected-text-format="count" >
                    <option ng-repeat="attribute in attributes">{{attribute}}</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
                    </select>
```

I have also tried the 'ng-options' in the select tag but it is also not working.

I think! ,it is not loaded due asyncronous call , please suggest the alternative solution or how to load data when the background rest call is complete in angular JS.
My rest is working fine. only data is not properly binding[image]

Like here my rest data is loaded and when I select it from dropdown it is showing up inthe selected list but not displaying in the list. I think just because of asynchronous nature of data loading in the frontend.

or Do i need to write any directive ?

Comment: Please share more code .

Comment: Have you updated $scope.attributes after getting data from backend?

Comment: you need to provide more context here, like where the HTML elements that have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` are at.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller may have different $scope.

Comment: No ! , I am successfully getting the data from controller. because when i select the first option from the dropdown it displays the value in the main select drop down